# What does menu blocks "Block title as link" option do?

Tags: blocks

The [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module has an option on each block titled "Block title as link". My interpretation of the description combined with some testing, is that if I leave the "Block title" setting out, the name of the menu will be used as the block title, and it *should* also be a link to the currently viewed menu item.

However, when I check the option and try it, I never get any links. I've been trying to follow the code, but I couldn't make any sense of it, so I believe my expectation on the functionality is wrong.

Comment: Block title as link: An overridden block title will not be a link.
Did you override block title?

Comment: Good catch, but the question text explicitly says I did not override it. :) If I wasn't clear on that point, please suggest an edit.

Answer (score 3):

For me it doesn't show the menu name, but the link to the parent menu item of the block. IE with a menu hierarchy like this:

```
<Main Menu>
-- a
---- b
------ c
------ d
------ e
-- f
-- g
```

If the block looks like this:

```
Title
c
d
e
```

Then having the block title as link makes the title a link to menu item b.